# How to retrieve data from firebase firestore into flutter using StreamBuilder and also used ListView.builder to show the values?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies, stream-builder

If i downgrade the version it works but i am facing problems when i use the below version.

cloud_firestore: ^1.0.0

firebase_core: ^1,0.0

And flutter sdk version: 2.0.1

I am trying to imaplement the code.
`streamSnapshot.data.length` does not work

```
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('chats/UMrLSClddfvaw9wV0hs6/messages')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> streamSnapshot) =>
            streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none
                ? Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: streamSnapshot.data,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: Text('This works'),
                    ),
                  ),
      ),
```

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: itemCount needs length. But how i get the length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this:

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> streamSnapshot) =>
```

into this:

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) =>
```

Then in the `itemCount` you can do:

```
itemCount: streamSnapshot.data.docs.length
```